# Porting C++ Win32 app to linux app

Tags: c++, linux

I am converting a C++ Win32 app to Linux, I have problem in types and functions which is used in Win32 app, I have solved types problem (by using typedef and micros) but I don't know which function I should use instead of these functions ?

-[CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

-[ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

-[GetFileSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

-GlobalAlloc

-wsprintf

-GlobalFree

Comment: Is your application a graphical application? Did you consider using some portability library? For instance, Qt and Gtk runs on both systems... (and both Qt and Gtk provides a low level layer usable without any GUI)

Comment: ry using C standard functions rather than Win API calls

Comment: Actually my app is reading a bitmap image and sends it to printer after some modifications , and I am using Anjuta in openSUSE 12.3 and I am not enough time to migrate the codes to Qt or ...

Comment: I believe migrating it to Qt (or perhaps Gtk) would be quicker than anything else.

Comment: Does Qt implemented the mentioned functions ?

Comment: Qt give you abstractions wrapping these functions...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Integrating all of Qt just to wrap these few functions seems like overkill.  Wrapping them yourself wouldn't take more than 10 or 20 lines of code (and could be generally usable: I know I've got wrappers for the first three in my toolkit).

Comment: The last three are just Microsoft mispellings of standard C functions.

Comment: If you are really in a hurry, did you consider running the windows version of the program with Wine, instead? It will most likely work just fine, and Wine is very stable these days. Also, depending on how your program sends it to the printer, it may be a bit more work porting that to Linux than the rest of the program - which is also a case for using Wine instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, `CreateFile`, `ReadFile` can be replaced with standard C or C++ file management (that is `FILE *` or `fstream` type operations) - there are however some options you can't get to that way (such as "exclusive access" to the file), so the devil is, as usual, in the detail.

Edit: `fopen` will create and `fread` will read from a `FILE *`, `fstream::open` and `fstream::read` would be the functions to create and read from an `fstream`.

`GetFileSize` is typically done by "seek to the end of file, then get the file position". So, for `FILE *` use `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);` and `size = ftell();`, or `fstream::seekg();` and `fstream::tellg()` - don't forget to do a seek back to the beginning before you read from the file.

`GlobalAlloc` and `GlobalFree` should be fine to replace with the relevant of `malloc` or `new` and `free` or `delete` depending on exactly how it is used.

The standard function for printing into a string of `wchar_t` is `swprintf`, which should work on Windows as well, if the compiler is standards compliant.

The benefit of using the standard C(++) library is that you can now compile the code for both windows and linux, without changing the code. And it's unlikely that you'll be able to tell the difference in performance.

Comment: You can't get "exclusive access" in Unix, period, unless you use file locking (extra requests).  The most frequent reason for using `CreateFile` that I've seen, however, has been for transactional integrity.

Comment: And as I've frequently pointed out, seeking to the end, then doing `ftell()`, isn't guaranteed to give you anything useful.  (But it will probably work under Windows and Unix.)

Answer (score 2):

- `CreateFile`: `open`
- `ReadFile`: `read`
- `GetFileSize`: `stat` (This gives you a lot of other
  information as well.   For the size, the field is `st_size`.)
- `GlobalAlloc` and `GlobalFree`: you can just use `malloc` and
  `free`.
- `wsprintf`: This looks like the same thing as the standard
  C function `swprintf`, which should be present on any system which supports C.

Comment: Using `open` and `read` will make the source code have to be different for Linux than Windows, using `fopen` and `fread` should allow the code to be compiled the same for both architectures.

Comment: It depends on why `CreateFile` and `ReadFile` were used.  At the very least, `fopen` and `fread` must use binary mode.  But the usual reason for using `CreateFile` to begin with is that you need modes that `fopen` doesn't support.

Comment: I've seen plenty of uses of `CreateFile` and `ReadFile` in the misdirected belief that it's "faster" than `fopen` and `fread`. But like I said in my answer, it does depend on what arguments are passed to `CreateFile`.